# Visual Studio Code Unable to install extension on macOs catalina : File Permission denied

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to install extensions in the Visual Studio Code 1.48.2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 VSCode is the latest and just installed.

I was having an issue so thought to re-install, I did but the issue still exists. I have checked in the console and found giving some file permission error but cannot understand it properly.

[image]